# Declaring variables and splitting "downto" in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have something like this in a declaration.

```
GPIO_1   : out std_logic_vector(35 downto 22);
```

it works fine. For diagnostics, I would like to break apart my `downto`. For example, if I want to skip 30. How would one write it?

```
GPIO_1 : out Std_logic_vector(35 downto 31, 29 downto 22);
```

???

Comment: ??? Can you please give a [mcve] of what you want, because I don't understand what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. So, either one would write:

```
GPIO_1a : out Std_logic_vector(35 downto 31);
GPIO_1b : out Std_logic_vector(29 downto 22);
```

or one would use concatenation by writing:

```
GPIO_1 : out Std_logic_vector(34 downto 22);
...
GPIO_1 <= some_internal_signal(35 downto 31) & some_internal_signal(29 downto 22);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would require two lines. I was looking for a simple fix for diagnostics.